# How to return an empty body in request scoped bean

Tags: java, jsf

I have a request scoped bean which has a postconstruct method. In this method i call a seperate function in a seperate EJB.
Based on the return value of the EJB i need to return an empty body with status code 200.

Answer (score 0):

For return http status code 200 you should create REST API endpoint and JSF bean must be you http client

Answer (score 0):

`ExternalContext` provides methods to set the required values for the response. After you need to call `FacesContext#responseComplete` to signal JSF that the response has already been generated.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class YourBean {

    ....

    @Inject
    private FacesContext context;

    @Inject
    private YourEjb yourejb;

    public void someMethod() throws IOException {
        yourejb.someEjbMethod();

        ExternalContext ec = context.getExternalContext();
        ec.responseReset();
        ec.setResponseContentLength(0);
        ec.setResponseStatus(200);
        context.responseComplete();
    }
}
```